# How to send parameters in a GET call with restlet?

Tags: java, curl, httpurlconnection, restlet

Confirmed the following in Curl:

This is working fine-

```
curl -X GET 'http://remoteUrl.com:8080/public/private/request/data?begin=12&end=20'
```

This is not working-

```
curl -X GET http://remoteUrl.com:8080/public/private/request/data?begin=12&end=20
```

So the whole purpose is to use the way first curl command in a java code with restlet to send the paramters in a GET request but unfortunately my code is not working.

**Code:**

```
    ClientResource clientResource = new     
    ClientResource("http://remoteUrl.com:8080/public/private/request/
    data?begin=12&end=20");
    Representation clientText = clientResource.get();
```

**Error Log:**

```
INFO: Unable to read a header
java.io.IOException: Parameter or extension has no name. Please check your value
    at org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderReader.readNamedValue(HeaderReader.java:499)
    at org.restlet.engine.header.CacheDirectiveReader.readValue(CacheDirectiveReader.java:65)
    at org.restlet.engine.header.CacheDirectiveReader.readValue(CacheDirectiveReader.java:38)
    at org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderReader.addValues(HeaderReader.java:282)
    at org.restlet.engine.header.CacheDirectiveReader.addValues(CacheDirectiveReader.java:50)
    at org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderUtils.copyResponseTransportHeaders(HeaderUtils.java:776)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.readResponseHeaders(ClientAdapter.java:129)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.updateResponse(ClientAdapter.java:191)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:105)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:119)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:153)
```

Comment: Can you give us the exact version of Restlet you use? Thanks!

Comment: org.restlet-2.3.1. Also note that after this exception I am getting a response as well. But this exception is such that even if I put it in try catch, it never disappears.

Comment: Thanks! In which environment do you this code (JSE, Android, ...)? In fact, I can't reproduce your problem...

Comment: Can you put in your question the exact content of the response (mainly headers) since the problem seems to occur when reading the response headers? Thanks!

Comment: I had a look at the Restlet source regarding your error and updated then my answer... Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

From the exception you give in your question, it seems that the value of the header `Cache-Control` isn't correct within the response. Restlet isn't able to parse it.

I guess that the value of this header is an empty string in the response...

Could you give us in your question the exact content of the response (mainly headers)?

Hope it helps you,
Thierry